# Extrair substring de uma linha em bash com um pattern

Tags: bash, awk

Boa tarde a todos,

Tenho um ficheiro de texto com diversas linhas com colunas fixas:

```
 11Sala                                    1:4     FF
```

A primeira coluna tem a identificação, e a segunda tem os dados que quero apanhar (`1:4`), mas quando tenho linhas em que a identificação, por exemplo tem sala, sala1, sala2, apanho todas as linhas e não quero.

quero apanhar os dígitos antes dos dois pontos (:) e depois 1 e 4

Estou a usar este código:

a variável CL contem:

'Sala' na primeira linha

'Sala1' na segunda linha

'Sala2' na terceira linha

```
 declare -i TblStart=$(awk -F, "/$CL/ { print substr(\$0,48,10) }" /home/ficheiro.txt | cut -d ":" -f 1)

 declare -i TblEnd=$(awk -F, "/$CL/ { print substr(\$0,48,10) }" /home/ficheiro.txt | cut -d ":" -f 2)
```

Como fazer?

Comment: Qual é o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas supondo que o arquivo tenha o formato:

```
Sala                                    1:4     FF
Sala1                                   2:5     FF
Sala2                                   3:6     FF
```

E você queira apenas os números da segunda coluna:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

  start=$(echo $line | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')
  end=$(echo $line | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')

  echo $start
  echo $end

done < ficheiro.txt
```

Obs: Da pra melhorar o script...

**EDIT**

---

Como sugerido pelo @fedorqui, uma solução de uma linha(estilo geek):

```
awk '{split($2, a, ":"); print a[1]; print a[2]}' ficheiro.txt
```

Comment: `awk '{split($2, a, ":"); print a[1]; print a[2]}' ficheiro.txt`

Comment: @fedorqui Boa! Era disso que falava! :)

Comment: _Estilo geek_? :/